# Android preferences: get all set values when keys are unknow

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, persist

Can someone tell me please how can I get all string set values from a preference file, I saved in this file just set lists?

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(); 
set.add("value1");
set.add("value2");
set.add("value3");
editor.putStringSet("key", set);
```

The problem I don't know which key will be chosen to save. Is this possible to read all available set lists without knowing the keys?

Comment: I want to save some projects for example key= project5, value1 = place, value2= person and so on. So I don't know which project the user wish to save it persistently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this.

```
Map<String, ?> keys = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() instanceof Set) {
        Log.e("Set values", entry.getKey() + ": " +
                entry.getValue().toString());
    }
}
```

Although am not sure why would you want to do that? Because you should set the data with some specific keys, so that you can fetch the same at a later time. What do you mean by  `I don't know which key will be chosen to save`?

Comment: Thank you I will try that. I mean that I don't know which entry the user will be choose to save the entry in the preferences file.

Comment: It works perfectly, I just had a problem because I don't use a defaultSharedPreferences.